# Geoserver :Is it possible to cluster polygons in sld?

Tags: geoserver, polygon, sld, clustering

Is that even possible?

This is my work area:

[image: Zoom in]

And I want this to be clustered when I zoomed out. Like this:

[image: Zoom out]

Comment: does each cluster share a unique common value?

Comment: I think that would be a 'yes'. Here, see my screenshot:

 [Image_Link](https://ibb.co/nPD8vk)